# Random home button appears in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

Not sure if anyone has had this problem but there is a random home button that  shows up on my UWP app whenever I click a button within the app. The button does not exist in my application so I'm not sure where it is coming from. it appears in the same place every time and if I drag the window it doesn't move with it. It appears every time i click on a button control, then fades away after 4-5 seconds.

[image]

***UPDATE***
After further investigation I found what was happening. I have a webview control in the background and button controls in the front view. The website I navigate to (vans.co.uk) has it's store logo in the top left corner and when the mouse hovers over it, the "Home" tooltip appears. However, if I click on a button control anywhere on the screen, and change the visibility property of that button to collapsed in the click method, this "Home" tooltip appears. There must be some sort of event passed to the webview when a button is collapsed on click. This happens on any website, not just vans.co.uk, but the logo on this site is positioned in a way that the tooltip pops up. I wrote a simple app to recreate this:

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="HomeTootipBug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HomeTootipBug"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="webView" Visibility="Visible" DefaultBackgroundColor="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="100" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


namespace HomeTootipBug
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public bool compOut = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            webView.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.vans.co.uk"));
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a Tooltip not a Button - maybe look for something like this ToolTipService.ToolTip or something with text "Home" might be where that's coming from?

Comment: I've checked, the word "Home" doesn't even appear any any of the code at all. And I don't use ToolTipService anywhere in the app.

Comment: Are you using any third party toolkits?

Comment: Show your code, 100% something in your code

Comment: There is a lot of code

Comment: Without the code, we can not find where the issue happens and can not help you with the issue. On other hand, you can debug your app by searching some key words such as Button, Home...

Comment: I figured out what was causing the tooltip to appear and added code to recreate the issue, still have no idea why this happens and don't know of a proper fix.

Comment: What is the real effect you want to implement? Why do you hide and show the Button just on the same time? As what I see, during the internal, the webview gets focus and popups the event to the webview html content, so the tooltip shows.

Comment: In my application I don't hide and show the button at the same time, I just did that so you could see the tooltip multiple times without having to run the app again. But your explanation makes sense, it's focusing on the webview when the button is hidden. I was able to stop the tooltip from showing, so thank you. But I did more of a hack than a proper fix, still don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a compination of how the vans.co.uk works & how the UWP event handling works. In short, collapsing the button in click allows the WebView to receive focus, quite likely prompting vans web site to run JS which shows the Home-button.

You can monitor what happens by adding GotFocus event handler to the WebView. If you start from scenario where your button isn't collapsed:

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        Debug.WriteLine("Button Clicked "+ e.OriginalSource.ToString());
    }

    private void WebView_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Webview got focus");
    }
```

You can see the following debug output when you click the button few times:

```
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
```

Now if you remove the comments from code, enabling the collapsing:

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        Debug.WriteLine("Button Clicked "+ e.OriginalSource.ToString());
    }

    private void WebView_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Webview got focus");
    }
```

You can see the following output in debug console after few clicks:

```
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Webview got focus
Webview got focus
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Webview got focus
Webview got focus
Button Clicked Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
Webview got focus
```

It's quite likely that this is related how UWP deals with [event bubbling & routed events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview).